# Wordpress - admin pre-output hook with permission check

Tags: wordpress

On my wordpress plugin, I want to make a "export table as CSV" feature that can only be downloaded by the highest kind of admin.

What is the best hook to use and how to check for the permission?

```
<?php
add_action( 'admin_init', 'xxxxxx_admin_init' );


function xxxxxx_admin_init() {
   # admin.php?page=xxxxxx_admin_page&&mode=export_csv
   if ($_GET['page'] == 'xxxxxx_admin_page' && $_GET['mode'] == 'export_csv') {
      if (!user_can('export')) {
         die("Permission denied");
      }
      header("Content-type:text/csv");
      echo "column\r\nvalue\r\nvalue";
      die();
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance

edit: added die(); after csv echo

Comment: How to check permission ? what access level the users need to export csv from your plugin ?

Comment: highest possible, administrators right?

Answer (score 1):

Check for one of the admin abilities, like `user_can('manage_options')`

[Wordpress Roles and Capabilities](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities)

Comment: Right, it's ok as well. But if you have the multisite network and want to check for Superadmin - use manage_sites ability to check.

Comment: seems like I didn't used user_can() properly up there

Comment: I need to use current_user_can()